# How are super, pass, yield and other keywords are implemented in Python?

Tags: python, yield

I was asked this question in a recent interview. And I know super is the way to get the super class, pass has no effect but to close a function or class declaration, yield is used in generator. But I have no idea how they are implemented in Python.

I searched and only get the answer for super: [How is super() in Python 3 implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126727/how-is-super-in-python-3-implemented), anybody can answer for others?

Comment: Do you know how compilers work? What a "lexer" and a "parser" do? `pass` and `yield` are implemented  there.

Comment: They just compiled (or not in case of `pass`) into specific PVM instructions (in CPython). Also that answer you mention - is CPython code.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer No, I don't. :(  Can you explain it more detailed?

Comment: @myaut I'm reading that article but seem is not what I pretended. I'm pool with C and lexer, so have learn them first to get this question understand?

Comment: How these are implemented will depend on the um, implementation.  So you need to look at the source code, which could change at any release.   Sounds like a daft question unless you are writing your own Python implementation.  How they are used is a different question.

Comment: @kxxoling In CPython, the interpreter reads your `.py` files and compiles the code into its own "bytecode" representation that is then executable. The "lexer" is the first component, it will read the Python code and produce a stream of "tokens". If it reads "pass", it will report something like "TK_PASS". These tokens are then consumed by the "parser", who does not care anymore how keywords are spelled, but knows where they are allowed to occur (e.g., that `def return yield` is invalid syntax). Read the Wikipedia articles on "Lexical analysis" and "Parsing" to learn more.

Comment: Umm... Seems I have a lot to learn to get the answer of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` is not a keyword in python, it's a variable like `int` or `range`.
Keywords like `pass`, `yield`, `def`, `if`, ... are consumed by the parser to build an AST (Abstract-Syntax-Tree). You can play with the AST by yourself with the `ast`-module of python.
The AST is then turned in some lower level machine or virtual machine code by the code generator, ready for execution.