# `super()` keyword doesn't work properly in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.7, and I get an error in the code below. It looks like the `super()` keyword doesn't work properly with list comprehensions. I want to know the cause.

```
class A(object):
    def hello(self):
        return 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        why_error = [
            super().hello() for i in range(2) for j in range(2)
        ]
        print(why_error)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        why_no_error = [
            super().hello(),
            super().hello(),
            super().hello(),
            super().hello()
        ]
        print(why_no_error)

c = C()
b = B()
```

And the execution result is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    b = B()
  File "test.py", line 8, in __init__
    super().hello() for i in range(2) for j in range(2)
  File "test.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    super().hello() for i in range(2) for j in range(2)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Comment: `super(B, self).hello()` would work I think

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3's super and comprehensions -> TypeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895302/python3s-super-and-comprehensions-typeerror)

Comment: beside finding this approach hideous ... `why_error = [  self.hello() for i in range(2) for j in range(2) ]`  would work without the super()

Comment: You're right. But what I'm curious about is why class B and C should work differently.

Comment: Note that using ``super`` to access a different method (e.g. ``hello`` from ``__init__``) generally indicates that your class is violating [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), because it means ``self.hello`` cannot be substituted for ``super().hello``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comprehensions are run in a separate scope -- which is also why `i` and `j` are not leaked -- that is *nested* in the method. The automatic insertion of `__class__` and `self` for zero-argument super does not work in such a nested scope.

Use the two-argument form of `super` instead:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        why_error = [
            super(B, self).hello() for i in range(2) for j in range(2)
        ]
        print(why_error)
```

In the case of class `C`, a list *literal* is used, not a list *comprehension*. Literals do not use a separate scope.

> ## [Displays for lists, sets and dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)
>
> For constructing a list, a set or a dictionary Python provides special syntax called “displays”, each of them in two flavors:
>
> - either the container contents are listed explicitly, or
> - they are computed via a set of looping and filtering instructions, called a comprehension.
>
> [...]
>
> However, aside from the iterable expression in the leftmost for clause, **the comprehension** is executed in a separate implicitly nested scope. This ensures that names assigned to in the target list don’t “leak” into the enclosing scope.

Comment: Simpler solution (without repeating class name or `self`): Put `s = super()` outside the listcomp, then call  `s.hello()` inside it. The `super` magic (performed on construction, not use) now executes in the correct scope.

Comment: @ShadowRanger If one is inclined to avoid the overhead, ``hello = super().hello`` outside the scope works better.