# Multiple inheritance problem with super()

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, mixins, super

I'm having a problem with multiple inheritance that I can't seem to figure out. Here is a very abstracted minimal example that reproduces my error (my code is much more complex than this).

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.x = x

class Mixin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = [1,2,3]

    def children(self):
        return [super().__init__(x=num) for num in self.numbers]

class CompositeThing(Mixin, Thing):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def test(self):
        for child in self.children():
            print(child.x)

obj = CompositeThing()
obj.test()
```

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance), I expect the `children()` method to return a list of `Thing`s built up from `self.numbers`. Instead, I get `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`. Incidentally, the same thing happens if I don't call the constructor and allow children to return `super()` 3 times (i.e., the uninstantiated superclass). Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out. There were two problems: (1) [`super()` doesn't work as expected inside comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895302/python3s-super-and-comprehensions-typeerror) because comprehensions in Py3 have their own scope - this was causing the `TypeError` I was experiencing. (2) What I was *really* trying to do was [create a *new instance* of the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61183492/pythonic-way-of-returning-instances-of-parent-class-from-child), rather than calling a method from the parent. I have posted a new question for just the latter problem for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In line 9 of your code, it looks like you are trying to call `__init__` of `object`. I am assuming you meant to have `Mixin` inherit from `Thing`.

```py
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.x = x

class Mixin(Thing):
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = [1,2,3]

    def children(self):
        return [super().__init__(x=num) for num in self.numbers] # Now calls Thing.__init__ instead of object.__init__

class CompositeThing(Mixin, Thing):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def test(self):
        for child in self.children():
            print(child.x)

obj = CompositeThing()
obj.test()
```

Comment: This is incorrect. In reality there are many different kinds of `Thing`s, so Mixin needs to stand alone and yet be able to instantiate whatever `Thing` is. My understanding of the MRO is that this is possible - or is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: It is possible, but not using `super()`. Given that `Mixin` inherits directly from `object`, running `super()` will return `object` and not `Thing`. You can directly access `Thing` by using `Thing.__init__` instead of `super().__init__`. Perhaps a better solution would be to create another object which `Mixin` inherits from.

Comment: the problem is I won't know what kind of `Thing` my `Mixin` class will need until the final child (i.e. the leaf of the inheritance tree)

Comment: also, that doesn't explain why just putting `super()` in the definition of `children()` fails with `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`, as opposed to simply returning 3 references to the `object` classes