# Add dynamic property with class in Python metaclass

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, metaclass

I use mongoengine with django rest framework. My model:

```
import mongoengine as mongo
class Plan(mongo.Document):
    slug = mongo.StringField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    subplans = mongo.ListField(mongo.EmbeddedDocumentField('self'))
```

I'm need serializer that be looks like this:

```
class PlanSerializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):
    subplans = PlanSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
```

But that incorrect for Python. So I use metaclass for adding `subplans` field dynamicly:

```
class AddSubplanAttrMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        # this code is incorrect because PlanSerializer not in globals
        class_obj = globals()[name]
        dct['subplans'] = class_obj(many=True, required=False)
        return super(AddSubplanAttrMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class PlanSerializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer, metaclass=AddSubplanAttrMetaclass):

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
```

How I can set `PlanSerializer` class to property inside `__new__` method of metaclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have there is that when you try to either use the line 
`subplans = PlanSerializer(many=True, required=False)` and when trying with the metaclass, the line `class_obj = globals()[name]` when your PlanSerializerclass itself was not defined yet. (Check my answer at  [How is super() in Python 3 implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126727/how-is-super-in-python-3-implemented/28605694#28605694))

The correct way to do that in the metaclass would be to call the superclass's new first - that returns you the actual class object, and then call that object - something along:

```
class AddSubplanAttrMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, dct):
        # this code is incorrect because PlanSerializer not in globals
        class_obj = super(AddSubplanAttrMetaclass, cls).__new__(metacls, name, bases, dct)
        class_obj.subplans = class_obj(many=True, required=False)
        return class_obj
```

But that is both not needed, and might still have issues - as not all the class initialization is completed while you are still inside the metaclass's `__new__` (or even `__init__`) methods. For example, if the `__init__` method of `PlanSerializer` itself would make use of `super`, that call would fail - `super` can only be used after  class has been fully initialized.

However, you don't need a metaclass at all for that - you probably can simply set the `subplans` attribute as a descriptor - and retrieve the attribute lazily.

```
class PlanSerializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Plan

PlanSerializer.subplans = PlanSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

I said probably because this won't work if Mongo needs the attribute to be set when initializing the class itself - if that is the case, you can try resorting to a descriptor object. A descriptor is simply an object that implements the `__get__` method, like below. That is usually done with the `@property` decorator, but that would not work for class level attributes, which you need for this case.

```
class PlanSerializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):
    class Subplans(object):
        serializer = None
        def __get__(self,  instance, owner):
            if not self.serializer:
                self.serializer = PlanSerializer(many=True, required=False)   
            return  self.serializer
    subplans = Subplans()

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
```

In that way the usage of the call to  the `Subplans` class is delayed to when it is actually used, instead of the time of parsing the class body, and it should work.