# Auto instantiation of class after import in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass

I want to automatically instantiate some classes in Python just after their modules have been imported, so there is no need to direct instantiation call.
My setup can be stripped down to following code:

```
class MetaTest(type):

    _instances = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        super(MetaTest, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        MetaTest._instances[name] = cls()


class Foo(object):

    __metaclass__ = MetaTest

    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()

class Bar(Foo):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
```

But the instantiation fails on the `super` with:

```
    super(Foo, self).__init__()
NameError: global name 'Foo' is not defined
```

By any chance, could there be the way how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: Modify `sys.modules`

This is a Python 2 version.
Adding the class to its module works, because it solves the problem that the class does not exits yet when you use `super()`:

```
import sys

class MetaTest(type):

    _instances = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        setattr(sys.modules[cls.__module__], cls.__name__, cls)
        super(MetaTest, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        MetaTest._instances[name] = cls()


class Foo(object):

    __metaclass__ = MetaTest

    def __init__(self):
        print('init Foo')
        super(Foo, self).__init__()

class Bar(Foo):

    def __init__(self):
        print('init Bar')
        super(Bar, self).__init__()

print(MetaTest._instances)
```

Output:

```
init Foo
init Bar
init Foo
{'Foo': <__main__.Foo object at 0x10cef90d0>, 'Bar': <__main__.Bar object at 0x10cef9110>}
```

### Solution 2: Use the `future` library

The [future](http://python-future.org/) library offers as `super()` for Python 2 that works just like the one for Python 3, i.e. without arguments.
This helps:

```
from builtins import super

class MetaTest(type):

    _instances = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        super(MetaTest, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        MetaTest._instances[name] = cls()


class Foo(object):

    __metaclass__ = MetaTest

    def __init__(self):
        print('init Foo')
        super().__init__()

class Bar(Foo):

    def __init__(self):
        print('init Bar')
        super().__init__()

print(MetaTest._instances)
```

Output:

```
init Foo
init Bar
init Foo
{'Foo': <__main__.Foo object at 0x1066b39d0>, 'Bar': <__main__.Bar object at 0x1066b3b50>}
```

Comment: your solution 2 won't work due to the reasons I explain in my answer (that is: the paramaeterless form of "super" just works after the code in the metaclass is done). The first proposal is clever, and it could indeed work.

Comment: @jsbueno Thanks for your comment. But I do get two instances in `MetaTest._instances` with my solution 2. Do I miss something here?

Comment: Maybe it works in Python 2. I know it dos not work in Python 3 due to the research I made for another complicated, related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126727/how-is-super-in-python-3-implemented/28605694#28605694

Comment: You are right. It does not work in Python 3 (tested with 3.6). The dict is empty. Maybe it has something to do with how `super()` from `future` is actually implemented.

Comment: I actually have in the backbruner in my mind write a PEP for a "UserType" thing for a metaclass that gives total control over some of the processes one can't address by customizing "type", and are seldom used to justify complicating all class instantiation even more. Examples are the step for creation of the `__class__` cell, and the step to calling  `__init_subclass__` itself.

Comment: Thank you @mike, as for now I will use the first solution. Simple and does what it should. I should have thought about that.

Comment: Good that it works for you. Often, the simple solutions are hard ones to find. ;)

Comment: @jsbueno I think I have to correct myself. I forgot to use the Python 3 metaclass syntax `class Foo(object, metaclass=MetaTest):`. Doing so, my solutions 2 seems to work for Python 3 too.

Comment: Well, I tried it here with Python 3.6 and it worked. It certainly didn't work when I wrote the answer linked above. Seems like this behavior has changed across versions.

Answer (score 2):

First note:

for this sort of code, it is easier to be using Python 3. More about this on the first solution and at the end of the answer.

So, the name of the class itself `Foo` won't, obviously, be available inside the body of `class Foo`: this name is only bound after the class instantiation is completely performed.

In Python 3, there is the parameterless version of `super()` call, which can direct one to the superclass with no need for a explicit reference to the class itself. It is one of the few exceptions the language make to its very predictable mechanisms. It binds data to the `super` call at compile time.  However, even in Python 3 it is not possible to call a method that makes use of `super` while the class is still being istantiated - i.e. before returning from the metaclass `__new__` and `__init__` methods. The data needed by the parameterless `super`  is silently bound after that.

However, in Python 3.6+ there is a mechanism that even precludes a metaclass: a class method named `__init_subclass__` will be called on the superclasses *after* a class is created, and it could make normal use of (parameterless) super. This would work with Python 3.6:

```
class Base:

   _instances = {}

   def __init_subclass__(cls):
        __class__._instances[cls.__name__] = cls()

   ...

class Foo(Base):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Here, `__class__` (not `obj.__class__`) is another magic name, available along with parameterless `super`, that always reference the class within which body it is used, never a subclass.

Now, a couple considerations on other methods: no code within the metaclass itself could work to instantiate a class, and the class methods needing to have a reference to the class in its name do not help. A class decorator would also not work, because the name is only bound after the return from the decorator. If you are coding your system within a framework which have an event loop, you could, on the metaclass `__init__` schedule an event to create a class instance - that would work, but you need to be coding within such a context (gobject, Qt, django, sqlalchemy, zope/pyramid, Python asyncIO/tulip are examples of frameworks which have an event system that could make the needed callbacks)

Now, if you really need this in Python 2, I think the easiest way is to create a function to be called at the footer of each of your modules that would "register" the recently created classes.
Something along:

```
class MetaTest(type):

    _instances = {}

def register():
    import sys
    module_namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals

    for name, obj in f_globals.items():
        if isinstance(obj, MetaTest):
            MetaTest._instances[obj.__name__] = obj()
```

again: a a call to this "register" function should come at the last line of each of your modules.

The "meta" thing in here is introspecting the frame of the caller function itself to get its global variables automatically. You can get rid with it by making `globals()` a required explicit parameter to the register function, and keeping the code easier to understand by third-parties.

## Why Python 3

As of today, Python 2 is 2 years from End of Line. And a lot of improvements have been happening in the language in the last 8 years, including features in the class and metaclass models. I've seem a lot of people seems to stick with python 2 because as "python" is linked to Python 2 in their Linux installs, they think that is the default. Not true: it is just there for backwards compatibility - more and more Linux install use python3 as the default Python, usually installed alongside Python 2. And for your projects, it is nicer to use an isolated environment created with virtuaelnv anyway.

Comment: I like the idea of that registration function.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. However I'm stuck with Python 2.7 as my code runs in embedded Python (inside 3dsMax to be precise).
Initially I wanted to do the registrator function, but later I wanted to do auto instantiation so users of the framework I'm creating don't need to register manually. I will use @mike solution for now, but if it fails, you have a great call with using event system for that as I have whole Qt available.

Answer (score 0):

What jsbueno said. I've been trying to make this work in Python 2, but without much success. Here's the closest I got:

```
class MetaTest(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        super(MetaTest, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        MetaTest._instances[name] = cls()

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaTest

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

for name, obj in Bar._instances.items():
    print name, obj, type(obj)
```

**output**

```
Foo <__main__.Foo object at 0xb74626ec> <class '__main__.Foo'>
Bar <__main__.Bar object at 0xb746272c> <class '__main__.Bar'>
```

However, if you try to give either `Foo` or `Bar` `__init__` methods, then it all falls to pieces, for the reasons given by jsbueno.

Here's a Python 3.6 version using the argless form of `super` that's more successful:

```
class MetaTest(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print('cls: {}\nname: {}\nbases: {}\nattrs: {}\n'.format(cls, name, bases, attrs))
        super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        MetaTest._instances[name] = cls()

class Foo(metaclass=MetaTest):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

for name, obj in Bar._instances.items():
    print(name, obj, type(obj))
```

**output**

```
cls: <class '__main__.Foo'>
name: Foo
bases: ()
attrs: {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Foo', '__init__': <function Foo.__init__ at 0xb7192dac>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0xb718c2b4: MetaTest object at 0xb718d3cc>}

cls: <class '__main__.Bar'>
name: Bar
bases: (<class '__main__.Foo'>,)
attrs: {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Bar', '__init__': <function Bar.__init__ at 0xb7192d64>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0xb718c2fc: MetaTest object at 0xb718d59c>}

Foo <__main__.Foo object at 0xb712514c> <class '__main__.Foo'>
Bar <__main__.Bar object at 0xb71251ac> <class '__main__.Bar'>
```

---

I must confess that I'm not very comfortable with this whole concept of classes creating an instance of themself automatically: "Explicit is better than implicit". I think jsbueno's suggestion of using a registration function is a good compromise.