# Inside of `__new__`, why is `cls` required instead of `args[0]`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, constructor-overloading

I have two almost identical implementations of the `__new__` method for a class.

However, in one case, there is an error message.

In the other case, it works fine.

```python
class Klass1():
    # causes RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
    def __new__(*args):
        obj = super().__new__(args[0])
        return obj

class Klass2():
    # This code here works just fine   
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        return obj

instance1 = Klass1()
instance2 = Klass2()
```

Why would it matter whether we write `cls` or `args[0]`?

What is causing the `RuntimeError` exception to be raised?

Comment: The zero-argument form of `super` requires a tiny bit of compiler magic which is, apparently, broken by a function declaration that doesn't have at least one explicit parameter.

Comment: BTW, that magic is quoted in an answer over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13128705/14122 (albeit an older version from Python 3.3)

Comment: `super` does not have default parameter values in the usual sense (e.g., `def super(x=3, y=5): ...`, because the values used are determined when `super` is *called*, not when `super` is defined. (Also, `super` is a type, not a function, but the idea is the same.)